# Show all the groups a host is in in an ansible inventory

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible (v2.9.11) set of playbooks with about 80 servers, doing various different things. I am trying to structure things into groups, with subgroups.

Is it possible to easily see all the groups that a host is a member of? Especially if it shows me the hierarchy, as in "Host H₁ is in group G₁ which is a child group of group G₂"

Comment: Would it be possible to learn the use-case where groups' hierarchy is needed?

Answer (score 4):

[Special variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) `group_names` keeps *"List of groups the current host is part of"*. There is no info about the groups' hierarchy available in Ansible.

Answer (score 2):

Based on inspiration from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/706901/106012, I came up with this solution to list the groups for a particular host:

```
ansible-inventory --list | jq -r 'map_values(select(.hosts != null and (.hosts | contains(["myhost"])))) | keys[]'
```

This doesn't take into account nested groups, but works for the flat group structure in my small ansible installation.  I'm sure someone with better `jq` chops than I could fix this deficiency.